# Powershell's Copy-Item gives inconsistent results on file system and registry

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to use Powershell's `Copy-Item` commandlet with the `-Recurse` and `-Force` parameters to copy settings from one registry key and overwrite the same settings (if they exist) in another key.  If I were using this same command on a file system, then any folders that exist in source and target would be overwritten in the target.

When using this command on the registry, however, if there are keys in the target that exist, the source key is copied as a subkey.  Example:

Starting state:

```
HKCU:Software\OldVendor\Program  
HKCU:Software\OldVendor\Program\Setting1  
HKCU:Software\OldVendor\Program\Setting2  

HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting1  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting2
```

Now if I run this command:

```
Copy-Item -Path "HKCU:Software\OldVendor\Program" -Destination "HKCU:Software\NewVendor" -Recuse -Force
```

I expect the same structure to be maintained.  In fact, the structure under NewVendor looks like this:

```
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting1  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting1\Setting1  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting2  
HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program\Setting2\Setting2
```

Can anyone tell me how to get Powershell to overwrite existing registry keys, instead of copying to subkeys?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you want to copy items and their values, those are properties, not keys. You can list them as follows:

```
get-itemproperty "HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program"
```

or u can use alias and omit quotes:

```
gp HKCU:Software\NewVendor\Program
```

Another, better way, which doesn't view powershell specific properties:

```
Get-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\NewVendor\Program | select -ExpandProperty Property
```

So, if u want to copy all the properties from one key to another:

```
Get-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Program | select -ExpandProperty Property | % {Copy-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Program -Destination HKLM:\SOFTWARE\AnotherProgram -Name $_ -Verbose}
```

You have to use foreach loop, beacuse Copy-ItemProperty cmdlet can copy only one property been specified.